# Device pointer in a device class (Cuda C++)

Tags: c++, pointers, cuda

I would like to implement a device side vector class which encapsulates a pointer to the elements of the container.

After I instantiate an object of this class I have no access to the inside pointer. It always says 'Access violation writing location *some device memory address*'.

My code is the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

template <typename T>
class DeviceVector
{
private:
    T* m_bValues;
    std::size_t m_bSize;

public:
    __host__
    void* operator new(std::size_t size)
    {
        DeviceVector<T>* object = nullptr;
        cudaMalloc((void**)&object, size);
        return object;
    }

    __host__
    void operator delete(void* object)
    {
        cudaFree(object);
    }

    __host__
    DeviceVector(std::size_t size = 1)
    {
        cudaMemcpy(&m_bSize, &size, sizeof(std::size_t), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

        // At this cudaMalloc I get Access violation writing location...
        cudaMalloc((void**)&m_bValues, size * sizeof(T));

        // It's an alternative solution here
        T* ptr;
        cudaMalloc((void**)&ptr, size * sizeof(T));
        cudaMemcpy(&m_bValues, &ptr, sizeof(T*), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        // The memory is allocated
        // But I can't access it through m_bValues pointer
        // It is also Access violation writing location...
    }

    __host__
    ~DeviceVector()
    {
        // Access violation here if I use the second solution in the constructor
        cudaFree(m_bValues);
    }
};

int main()
{
    DeviceVector<int>* vec = new DeviceVector<int>();

    delete vec;

    return 0;
}
```

Note:
I have access to the size attribute.

So my questions are: 
How to allocate memory for this class to get access to the pointer inside?
Is this even possible to encapsulate a pointer into a class on the device?

Comment: SO [expects](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for questions like these ("why isn't this code working?"), that you provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Why does your constructor try to copy to `m_bSize` using the CUDA APIs?

Comment: Because the `size` parameter of the constructor is on host memory and the `m_bSize` attribute is on the device memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is illegal:

```
    cudaMalloc((void**)&m_bValues, size * sizeof(T));
```

because your `new` operator allocated the object on the device:

```
    cudaMalloc((void**)&object, size);
    return object;
```

and the constructor was called to operate on *that allocation*.  Therefore `&m_bValues` is taking the address of a *device* variable in host code which is illegal in CUDA.  If you do that, and then attempt to use it in host code (i.e. the `cudaMalloc` operation), you're going to get a seg fault.  `cudaMalloc` creates a device allocation of a particular size, and then stores the device pointer to that allocation in a variable that is expected to be *resident on the host*.  If you pass it a device address to store that pointer into instead, `cudaMalloc` will segfault trying to write the pointer value.

Your alternative solution is a somewhat better approach, and is the general idea when it's necessary to copy a pointer to a device allocation to a variable resident on the device.

But you've still basically made the allocation that `m_bValues` points to *inaccessible* from the host.  (`ptr`, being a temporary variable, won't help, and creating another variable in the class to hold a value like `ptr` won't help either because the *entire class* is allocated and resident on the device.) For the same reason that you're not allowed to use `&m_bValues` in the previous `cudaMalloc` operation, you won't be able to use it directly in any other host code (except as the target for `cudaMempcy` host->device when copying the pointer value itself).

I don't think there are any simple fixes for this.  I suggest re-crafting the object to live on the host, and provide appropriate host- and device-side allocations for corresponding pointers and parameters (like `size`).

It also seems like you're re-inventing the wheel.  You might want to investigate [thrust device vectors](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide) (which are easily usable with ordinary CUDA code.)

Anyway, this was the closest I could come up with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define cudaCheckErrors(msg) \
    do { \
        cudaError_t __err = cudaGetLastError(); \
        if (__err != cudaSuccess) { \
            fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: %s (%s at %s:%d)\n", \
                msg, cudaGetErrorString(__err), \
                __FILE__, __LINE__); \
            fprintf(stderr, "*** FAILED - ABORTING\n"); \
            exit(1); \
        } \
    } while (0)

template <typename T>
class DeviceVector
{
private:
    T* m_bValues;
    std::size_t m_bSize;
    std::size_t eleSize;
public:
    __host__
    void* operator new(std::size_t size)
    {
        DeviceVector<T>* object = NULL;
        object = (DeviceVector<T> *)malloc(size*sizeof(DeviceVector<T>));
        return object;
    }

    __host__
    void operator delete(void* object)
    {
        free(object);
    }

    __host__
    DeviceVector(std::size_t size = 1)
    {
        m_bSize = size;
        eleSize = sizeof(T);
        cudaMalloc(&m_bValues, m_bSize*sizeof(T));
        cudaCheckErrors("constructor cudaMalloc fail");
        cudaMemset(m_bValues, 0, m_bSize*sizeof(T));
    }

    __host__
    ~DeviceVector()
    {
        cudaFree(m_bValues);
        cudaCheckErrors("destructor cudaFree fail");
    }

    __host__
    T* getDevPtr(){
        return m_bValues;}

    __host__
    std::size_t getSize(){
        return m_bSize;}

    __host__
    std::size_t geteleSize(){
        return eleSize;}
};

int main()
{
    DeviceVector<int>* vec = new DeviceVector<int>();
    cudaMemset(vec->getDevPtr(), 0xFF, vec->getSize()*vec->geteleSize());
    cudaCheckErrors("vector fill fail");
    delete vec;

    return 0;
}
```

You've shown very little about how you want to interact with an object of this class, so I'm just guessing here.

Comment: I would like to use objects from this class only in `__global__` functions.
I'm trying to allocate all the memory on the device to avoid copying between host and device.
Is that possible to have an object on the device with a pointer which has an address to a device memory? If yes then how? :)

Comment: Okay, I realized that the best solution is that the object lives on the host and the memory allocated inside is going to be on the device.
Thanks for your help.